# running pig script

Tags: node.js, hadoop, apache-pig

I have Pig script and sample application which is written in Node.js. I just wanted to run Pig script from Node.js.

Comment: It's the same question of "Execute A Unix Command With Node.js", I think.

Comment: can you kindly give me a link or sample code from which I can run my Pig script file with node.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not used node.js. But here I find a link to show how to execute a unit command in node.js: http://www.dzone.com/snippets/execute-unix-command-nodejs

For example, if you want to run a pig script called foo.pig. Then you can try the following code:

```
var sys = require('sys')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { sys.puts(stdout) }
exec("pig -f foo.pig", puts);
```

You can replace `pig -f foo.pig` to any command that you use to run your pig script.